# Drag Drop Contents

Tags: c#, datagridview, outlook, drag-and-drop

I want to Drag and Drop something into a DataGrid in WinForms. The functionality that he recognises the Drag Enter and Drag Drop are made. It works like a charm because i made text pop up when it enters and when its dropped.

Sadly i have no idea how to access the content of the thing (Outlook Contact) i dropped in there. My Goal is to Drop and Outlook Contact into the Data Grid and i want to have the things contained in the Contact like, Name, Email adress etc. and save it temporarily so that i can insert it into the Grid.

I hope some of you can help me and/or give me a clue on how to tackle this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`. There is a NuGet package for this.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
```

Create a instance for the `Outlook.Application` and get the selected items in your `DragDrop` Handler.

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application moOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
private void DragDropHandler(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var loExplorer = moOutlook.ActiveExplorer();
    var loSelection = loExplorer.Selection;

    foreach (object loItem in loSelection)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem loContactItem = (loItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem);
        if (loContactItem != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(loContactItem.EntryID);
            Console.WriteLine(loContactItem.Email1Address);
            Console.WriteLine(loContactItem.Email2Address);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code cannot be correct, nobody wants to start Outlook again.  Almost all Office objects have an Application property so you can get a reference back to the instance that generated the object.  ContactItem does.

Comment: What do you mean with "nobody wants to start Outlook again"? `new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application()` will fail if Outlook is not open. Create the `Application` can also do in the Handler and make an ExceptionHandling if failed.